# How to make an integer index row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame:

```
+-----+--------+---------+
|  usn|log_type|item_code|
+-----+--------+---------+
|    0|      11|    I0938|
|  916|      19|    I0009|
|  916|      51|    I1097|
|  916|      19|    C0723|
|  916|      19|    I0010|
|  916|      19|    I0010|
|12331|      19|    C0117|
|12331|      19|    C0117|
|12331|      19|    I0009|
|12331|      19|    I0009|
|12331|      19|    I0010|
|12838|      19|    I1067|
|12838|      19|    I1067|
|12838|      19|    C1083|
|12838|      11|    B0250|
|12838|      19|    C1346|
+-----+--------+---------+
```

And I want distinct `item_code` and make an index for each `item_code` like this:

```
+---------+------+
|item_code| numId|
+---------+------+
|    I0938|   0  |
|    I0009|   1  |
|    I1097|   2  |
|    C0723|   3  |
|    I0010|   4  |
|    C0117|   5  | 
|    I1067|   6  |
|    C1083|   7  |
|    B0250|   8  | 
|    C1346|   9  |
+---------+------+
```

I don't use `monotonically_increasing_id` because it returns a bigint.

Answer (score 3):

Using `monotanicallly_increasing_id` only guarantees that the numbers are increasing, the starting number and consecutive numbering is not guaranteed. If you want to be sure to get 0,1,2,3,... you can use the RDD function `zipWithIndex()`.

Since I'm not too familiar with spark together with python, the below example is using scala but it should be easy to convert it.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq("I0938","I0009","I1097","C0723","I0010","I0010",
    "C0117","C0117","I0009","I0009","I0010","I1067",
    "I1067","C1083","B0250","C1346")
  .toDF("item_code")

val df2 = df.distinct.rdd
  .map{case Row(item: String) => item}
  .zipWithIndex()
  .toDF("item_code", "numId")
```

Which will give you the requested result:

```
+---------+-----+
|item_code|numId|
+---------+-----+
|    I0010|    0|
|    I1067|    1|
|    C0117|    2|
|    I0009|    3|
|    I1097|    4|
|    C1083|    5|
|    I0938|    6|
|    C0723|    7|
|    B0250|    8|
|    C1346|    9|
+---------+-----+
```