# How to efficiently add a 32 bit monotonically increasing contiguous id to each record in a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this issue where we need an int primary key (and not a long primary key) that needs to be added to a data frame.

MonotonicallyIncreasingId won't work because it gives long by default and converting it to int would truncate things badly since the last 31 bits in it actually are row numbers.

Anyone done this kind of thing?

Comment: Are you using scala or python?

Comment: I am using Scala

Comment: I am now thinking what will be better - using row_number() over () in spark/sql or using zipWithIndex on the rdd

Comment: I believe using `zipWithIndex` should be more efficient. You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46537764/7579547

Comment: Yea, that's what I am going with right now!